# Dynamic Hair bug?

Tags: particles, hair

Maybe that's me who's doing something wrong, but as soon as I create a UV sphere, scale it a bit and apply Hair Particle - it's getting extremely messy.
Blender 3.1.2

How to reproduce:

1. Create UV Sphere
2. Scale it whatever direction
3. Apply Hair Particles
4. Turn on Dynamic
5. Bake

[A small YouTube recording of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft1tVtcJAQw)

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: Did you apply the scale to the sphere before baking?

Comment: Not sure i did. Im newbie to blender, so how should i apply the scale if i do that via object properties?

Comment: In Object mode, CTRL - A and choose "Scale" from the popup Apply menu or via the Object > Apply > Scale menu on the top toolbar.

Comment: If you're unsure you can check the [transform scale values in the side panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html) (key N) of the 3D viewport. After you applied the scale the transform values will be reset to 1.0 but the actual scale of the object is kept. A scale of one is important for physics and many other things, and it is a common mistake not to apply it.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow morning and will reply. Thank you for tips!

Comment: @John Eason
Yes, it worked like this, thank you. Will keep that in mind.  Thank you, once again, for tips!

Answer (score 0):

After transforming, while in object mode I have to hit CTRL + A to apply all the transformations I do to the object and after this hair works just fine.